# Place nginx frontcontroller out of webroot

Tags: nginx

Just as an experiment, I was trying to remove my `index.php` from the webroot in nginx and directly point to `app.php`, as the only thing the index file does is this:

```
<?php

chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
include 'app.php';
```

My nginx setup is pretty easy:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    root        /vagrant/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # some includes here
}
```

And simply pointing out of the web root does not work:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    root        /vagrant/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /../app.php?$query_string;
    }

    # some includes here
}
```

It is for me a bit hard to search for this case, as there are many problems popping up based on the used key words, but all related to another problem.

There is no *real* need for this, but with nginx such a powerful tool I can't imagine this is not possible. So, it it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need to set the index paragraph in your nginx config.
Try `index app.php;` and reload nginx.

Comment: How could that work? It is still outside the webroot. I have tried btw, but it didn't work. Probably because it is all relative to the web root.